# DatagridView collapse by column

Tags: c#, datatable, datagridview, grouping

Is there any simple way to collapse by column in datagridview (datatable)? 
I have table like:

```
N Names
1 Name1 
1 Name2
2 Name1 
2 Name2
```

And I want to collapse according to column N, so:

```
> 1 Name1
> 2 Name1
```